# rmarkdown: page break within a chunk?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Is it possible to make each of the numbers show up on a separate page?

````
---
title: "Page Break In Chunk"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r}
for(i in c(1:10))
{
   print(i)
} 
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `cat("\\newpage")` and results = "asis":

````
---
title: "Page Break In Chunk"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r results = "asis"}
for(i in c(1:10))
{
   print(i)
   cat("\\newpage")
} 
```
````

Output (not sure if this is what you want):

[image: output1]

Comment: I wonder how we can do this using purrr:map instead of a for lopp. purrr:map is much faster but works differently than a foor loop. It will print all the newpage characters before each item in the list printing out. Any solutions?